# Add data to HTTP GET request using urllib2

Tags: python, http, python-2.7, urllib2

If, for example, i send a request to google, it looks like thios in fiddler:

```
GET http://www.google.com HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: google.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: Python-urllib/2.7
```

and i want to make it look like this:

```
GET http://www.google.com HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: google.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: Python-urllib/2.7

a=112&b=2335
```

How can i do it using urllib2/1? 
Thanks!!

Comment: You can't. HTTP `GET` requests *have no body*. A GET request uses *URL parameters* instead: `GET http://www.google.com?a=112&b=2335 HTTP/1.1`.

Comment: Indeed, a POST and PUT can have a body. Aren't you looking for that?

Comment: Thanks! @Rvdk I googled it, but because my english is not really good i couldt find anything..

Comment: @user3611091: First you have to check what google wants. A GET/POST or PUT. Urllib2 is maybe to basic, use http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ (much easier). Here is more info about POST look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP).